# Formatting dataframe output into JSON records by group

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, group-by

my dataframe looks like this *`df`*:

```
       count_arena_users  count_users                    event   timestamp
0                   4458        12499                 football  2017-04-30
1                   2706         4605                  cricket  2015-06-30
2                    592         4176                   tennis  2016-06-30
3                   3427        10126                badminton  2017-05-31
4                    717         2313                 football  2016-03-31
5                    101          155                   hockey  2016-01-31
6                  45923       191180                   tennis  2015-12-31
7                   1208         2824                badminton  2017-01-31
8                   5577         8906                  cricket  2016-02-29
9                    111          205                 football  2016-03-31
10                     4            8                   hockey  2017-09-30
```

the data is fetched from a psql database, Now i want to generate the output of *`"select * from tbl_arena"`* in json format. But the json format that is desired has to be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "event": "football",
    "data_to_plot": [
      {
        "count_arena_users": 717,
        "count_users": 2313,
        "timestamp": "2016-03-31"
      },
      {
        "count_arena_users": 111,
        "count_users": 205,
        "timestamp": "2016-03-31"
      },
      {
        "count_arena_users": 4458,
        "count_users": 12499,
        "timestamp": "2017-04-30"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event": "cricket",
    "data_to_plot": [
      {
        "count_arena_users": 2706,
        "count_users": 4605,
        "timestamp": "2015-06-30"
      },
      {
        "count_arena_users": 5577,
        "count_users": 8906,
        "timestamp": "2016-02-29"
      }
    ]
  }
.
.
.
.
]
```

the values of all the columns are grouped based on the `event` column and later their occurance order of sub-dictionaries is decided based on `timestamp` column i.e. earlier dates appearing first and newer/latest dates appearing below it.

I'm using python 3.x and json.dumps to format the data into json style.

Comment: That's not vald JSON. Please fix it to describe what you're looking for.

Comment: (Also, I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: made necessary changes in the json format @coldspeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A high level process is as follows -

1. Aggregate all data with respect to `events`. We'd need a `groupby` + `apply` for this.
2. Convert the result to a series of records, one record for each event and associated data. Use `to_json`, with the `orient=records`.

```
df.groupby('event', sort=False)\
  .apply(lambda x: x.drop('event', 1).sort_values('timestamp').to_dict('r'))\
  .reset_index(name='data_to_plot')\
  .to_json(orient='records')
```

```
[
  {
    "event": "football",
    "data_to_plot": [
      {
        "count_arena_users": 717,
        "timestamp": "2016-03-31",
        "count_users": 2313
      },
      {
        "count_arena_users": 111,
        "timestamp": "2016-03-31",
        "count_users": 205
      },
      {
        "count_arena_users": 4458,
        "timestamp": "2017-04-30",
        "count_users": 12499
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Hi @coldspeed ,your approach seems to work but i want the sub-dictionaries to be sorted based on timestamp as well, (like 2017-01-31 data to appear before 2017-05-31 data) how do i achieve that?

Comment: @GabbarSingh Add a `sort_values` call inside `apply`.